# How to get gcov .gcda / coverage if test run was terminated?

Tags: c++, code-coverage, gcov, lcov

How to get .gcda (gcov)/ coverage if the test run is infinitive or the test run is long and I would like to get temporary results?
For example, I am interested in test coverage after 1 minute of execution.

`gcc -I${PWD} -fprofile-arcs -O0 --coverage program.c -o test-coverage`
`$ ./test-coverage`
`Terminated: 15`

If I terminate the process then .gcda wouldn't be created. Is any way to restore or get temporary values before process termination?

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the program so that the coverage data is flushed.

The following is for gcc compiler and gcov.

```
// Reference: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov-and-Optimization.html
// pre 11 gcc : extern "C" void __gcov_flush(void);
extern "C" void __gcov_dump(void);

[[noreturn]] void terminateHandler()
{
  __gcov_dump();
  std::abort();
}
```

In `main()`:

```
  std::set_terminate(&terminateHandler);
```

Given you have to build for coverage you can conditionally compile the above code.

You may need to also link against the gcov library.